# Average of Values of Different Percentage Lengths

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

| ID | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 84 |
| A | 1 | 90 |
| A | 2 | 76 |
| A | 3 | 98 |
| B | 0 | 64 |
| B | 1 | 81 |
| C | 0 | 89 |
| C | 1 | 76 |

I need to take the mean of the first 10% of values for each ID.

I used to do a similar process with the slice_head function, but previously I had taken the same length for each variable and used aggregate (grouped by ID) with the new data frame. Now that the lengths of each ID are different, slice keeps giving an error.

I have attempted map2 and lapply, but I cannot quite get it to work.

Comment: How do you define 10% of 5 rows? 10% of 2 rows? Or do you mean to get 10% value for each row? Please provide an example of what you want to achieve to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: My data frame is much larger. This is just an example. The entire data set I have has roughly 500 unique IDs with up to 50 rows each.

Comment: @Adam Quek OP meant 10% of all rows corresponding to particular ID. For eg, if there were 100 rows of A, OP would want mean of 1st 10 values.

Answer (score 0):

In the original data, I am hoping that the number of data points for each ID will be far more

```
jnk<-data.frame(ID=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",2),rep("C",2)),Time=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,0,1),Value=c(84,90,76,98,64,81,89,76))
```

Mean of 1st 10% of each ID:

```
> mean(jnk$Value[which(jnk$ID=="A")[1:(length(jnk$Value[which(jnk$ID=="A")])*0.1)]])
> mean(jnk$Value[which(jnk$ID=="B")[1:(length(jnk$Value[which(jnk$ID=="B")])*0.1)]])
> mean(jnk$Value[which(jnk$ID=="C")[1:(length(jnk$Value[which(jnk$ID=="C")])*0.1)]])
```

You will get mean values of 1st 10% with sufficiently high number of data points corresponding to each ID

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you could use `slice` with `ceiling` to get the first 10% percent per group and then `summarise` the `mean` of your value column like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                 Time = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                 Value = c(84, 90, 76, 98, 64, 81, 89, 76))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1:ceiling(0.1 * n())) %>%
  summarise(avg_value = mean(Value))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   ID    avg_value
#>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 A            84
#> 2 B            64
#> 3 C            89
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Please note: results are weird, because of less data.